# Android Volley StringRequest not working sometimes

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using the code below to get some local video URL from an API.

```
public void getVideoAds(String serverURL){
    String url = "http://"+serverURL+"/video/";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject defaultObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("default");
                JSONArray videoObj = jsonObj.getJSONArray("videos");

                defaultUrl = defaultObj.getString("url");

                for (int i = 0; i < videoObj.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject video = videoObj.getJSONObject(i);

                    VideoAd v = new VideoAd();
                    v.setName(getVideoNameFromLink(video.getString("url")));
                    v.setUrl(video.getString("url"));
                    v.setVideoId(video.getInt("id"));
                    v.setVersion(video.getInt("version"));
                    v.setLocalPath("");

                    vidArrLst.add(v);
                }

                playLoopVideo();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getVidAds res err: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "VideoAds Err: "+error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "getVidAds err: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

And inside `onCreate()`, I initialize `RequestQueue` like this.

```
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Sometimes, `getVideoAds()` works. Sometimes, it doesn't work. The weird thing as well is that I'm not getting any error even after using `Exception` on my `catch()`. If it doesn't work, I do a `Clean Project -> Rebuild Project -> Make Project` and it works again. But after a few builds, mostly just 1 more build, it stops working again.

If you want to know more about playLoopVideo, look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55277277/exoplayer-not-playing-anymore-stuck-on-player-state-buffering?noredirect=1#comment97285583_55277277) I made. It's about the video playing part of my app. It currently doesn't play the video if I try to play it inside the `onResponse` of getVideoAds that's why I made a different question for it because maybe if I fix my `Volley` the video would play again.

This is my build.gradle(app) if you need it.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "biz.net.com.streamer"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

UPDATE:

This is really weird. My `getVideoAds()` method is called inside another method that calls a method the makes a `StringRequest` on a different API on the same server. To make it easier to understand below is the code for it.

```
private void getAdvertisements(final String serverURL){
    getVideoAds(serverURL);
    getMessageAds(serverURL);

    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Updating ads marquee");
                    getMessageAds(serverURL);
                }
            },
            300000);
}
```

Currently, the API that `getMessageAds()` calls don't return anything. I tried to comment it and the handler below and it finally worked. Even the video playing worked. I then tried to uncomment `getMessageAds()` and add a few messages on the server, everything is working fine. But after I remove the messages, it stops working again.

What could be the reason for this to happen?

Comment: `new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Log.d("Error", error.toString());
        }
    });` 

try to debug here. If any error occurred then you will get the error here.

Comment: As I've said, I'm not getting any error anywhere. In my real code, I even have a `Toast` inside `Response.ErrorListener` but it show up. This is the `Toast` I have inside the `Response.ErrorListener`. `Toast.makeText(ctx, "VideoAds Err: "+error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Have you checked `catch` block?

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: @Al-Amin sorry. What I mean is that the `Toast` doesn't show up. Some typo error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in volley

```
  stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 3, 1.0f));
```

Comment: which `StringRequest` do I put code? I got 2 `StringRequest` on my app.

Comment: just put above this code:->  queue.add(stringRequest);

Comment: But I don't really need to do a retry after getMessageAds() fails because it doesn't really have anything to get from the server currently.

Comment: It is not for retry only.it is for  long request .if your server delay to put some data so you can use this

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll try using that someday